# Deserializing a DNS packet object in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, serialization, dns

I have a DNS packet class which looks like this (I am pasting only part of it):

```
class DNSPacket {

public:
    struct DNSHeader {
        unsigned int ID :16; 
        unsigned int QR :1;  
        unsigned int OPCODE :4;  
        unsigned int AA :1;   
        unsigned int TC :1;  
        unsigned int RD :1;    
        unsigned int RA :1;   
        unsigned int Z :3;   

        unsigned int RCODE :4;
        unsigned int QDCOUNT :16;
        unsigned int ANCOUNT :16;
        unsigned int NSCOUNT :16;
        unsigned int ARCOUNT :16;
    };

private:
    DNSHeader header;
    std::vector<DNSQuestion> questions;
    std::vector<DNSAnswer> answers;
    std::vector<DNSAnswer> nameservers; // TODO: DNSAnswer?
    std::vector<DNSAnswer> add_records; // TODO: DNSAnswer?
}
```

What would be the right way to deserialize a `char` array into this object? The options I have are: overloading `>>` operator, adding a separate class to deserialize it to read and deserialize the data reading byte after byte and using `reinterpret_cast()`.

I want to create a **fast, modern implementation in C++11**. Which way should I choose? Also, how should I deserialize the bitfields - should I stick with bitwise operations?

Comment: What is the format of the char array?

Comment: It's a UDP dataframe encapsulating some (question or answer) DNS packet.

Comment: Your structure is wrong, according to [this](http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/networking/terms/dns-message-format.html) the `Z` field is three bits.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks for pointing this, fixed.

Comment: Using 96 bits instead of the previous 94 makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do it would be to treat word 2 (bits 16 to 31) as a single unsigned 16-bit integer (e.g. `uint16_t`) and simply get the bits by using bit-wise AND and SHIFT operations. All the other words can be read the same way, but used more or less as-is (after converting from network byte order to host byte order of course).

To get word X word as an `uint16_t` you have to do some casting:

```
uint16_t wordX = *reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(&your_array[X]);
```

Note that for the second word, since they are really just bits they are in the order specified, no byte order conversion is done on them.

Comment: What about endianness? Thete is no indication about which platform is he working on.

Comment: @marom Unless a RFC says otherwise, words longer than 8 bits should always be in network byte order, no matter the protocol.

Comment: that's right for the data coming from the network but most platforms nowadays are little endian, so for 16 bits words should have bytes reeversed. uint16_t wordX = (your_array[X] << 8) + your_array[X+1]

Comment: @marom You do know about the `ntohs` function? And I do have a note about converting from network byte order in my answer.